# EXISTS function returns first values only

Tags: mdx, mdx-query

Can someone please help me out understand what am I doing wrong?
I have the following structure of my CUBE:

[image]

And I`m creating the following calculated member in MDX in Visual Studio:

CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[Current_State]

AS EXISTS([DWH Dim Work Item Current].[State].[State].Members,[DWH Dim Work Item Current].[Title].Currentmember).Item(0).Name,

VISIBLE = 1;

But for some reason I get only the first value (i.e. "Active") for every row in Excel:

[image]

Can someone please tell me what I`m doing wrong and how I should fix it?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The title of the first column in Excel is Project. Which attribute and dimension is that from? If you change the PivotTable to put `[DWH Dim Work Item Current].[Title]` on rows instead of Project does it work?

Answer (score 0):

Does `EXISTING` work any better?

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[Current_State]

  AS EXISTING([DWH Dim Work Item Current].[State].[State].MEMBERS).ITEM(0).NAME,

VISIBLE = 1;
```

Comment: No, unfortunately, doesn`t work at all (returns #Value)